# Javascript, replace a string with a variable value in aspx page for Google Analytics

Tags: javascript

How do I replace the `'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX'` with `'UA-AAAAAAAA-AA'` via script code in an ASPX page ?  I can assign mGoogle_Id "`UA-AAAAAAAA-AA`' from my session variable and that works.  But I don't know how to use the variable mGoogleID in the `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX']);` line.  You would think that just putting the variable mGoogleId would work, but it does not.

```
    var mGoogleId='<%=Session("Google_Id")%>';

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX']);

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', mGoogleId]); ***************** This Does Not Work *****

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Comment: So `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', mGoogleId ]);` doesn't work?  What happens when you try it?

Comment: Are you trying to push `mGoogle_Id` as your question says?  In your code, the variable is `mGoogleId`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to push mGoogleId onto your array?

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', mGoogleId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To push your variable (`mGoogleId`) into your array (`_gaq`), Use the following:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', mGoogleId]);
```

Comment: No - I want to replace the value with a session variable

Comment: Ah Sorry I misunderstood. Changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're already pretty much there:

```
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '<%=Session("Google_Id")%>']);
```